# Does Angular2 Support Composed Components With Transitive Version Conflicts?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, npm, polymer, web-component

I'm wondering whether I can build apps with AngularJS using top level components installed via NPM which may have child component dependencies that are the same but have different version numbers?

For example suppose component's A and B are used. Component A depends on component C:1.0.4 and component B depends on Component C:2.0.6.

The reason I'm curious is that the Polymer registry does not support transitive dependencies that have version conflicts: https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/326

AngularJS 2 seems to have a more well thought dependency injection and scope architecture so I'm hoping that it was designed with the above case in mind?

TIA, Ole

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular2, typescript peer invalid, can't import modules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39328936/angular2-typescript-peer-invalid-cant-import-modules)

Comment: AFAIK the whole application is built at once. Every used component has to be compatible with the Angular version you build with.

Comment: If it's not already solved by angular 4, then I think it's pretty darn close.  It looks like a module could import a bunch of private components and export a single new component, which would use these private components.  So getting warmer ...