# angular2, typescript peer invalid, can't import modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

**I have two issues, propably, its depend each other :**

1. i can't reguire/import sass@0.5.0
2. typescript works but i see error

**by command npm list:**

```
├── sass@0.5.0 extraneous
├── systemjs@0.19.27
├── typescript@1.8.10 peer invalid
├── typings@1.3.3
└── zone.js@0.6.17

npm ERR! extraneous: sass@0.5.0 C:\Users\AxOn\Documents\projects\NODETS+ANGULAR2\public\node_modules\sass
npm ERR! peer invalid: typescript@1.8.10 C:\Users\AxOn\Documents\projects\NODETS+ANGULAR2\public\node_modules\typescript
```

**propably, because of typescript@1.8.10 peer invalid i can't see module:**

**import { sass } from 'sass'; //error**

```
C:\Users\AxOn\Documents\projects\NODETS+ANGULAR2\public>npm install sass --save
npm WARN package.json angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 No README data
npm WARN excluding symbolic link index.js -> lib/sass.js
npm WARN excluding symbolic link lib\index.js -> sass.js
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\AxOn\Documents\projects\NODETS+ANGULAR2\public\node_modules\lite-server\node_modules\browser-sync\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client requires component-emitter@'1.1.2' but will load

npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\AxOn\Documents\projects\NODETS+ANGULAR2\public\node_modules\lite-server\node_modules\browser-sync\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\component-emitter,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 1.2.0
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "sass" "--save"
npm ERR! node v4.2.6
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.12
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID

npm ERR! peerinvalid The package typescript@1.8.10 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/compiler-cli@0.6.0 wants typescript@^2.0.2

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\AxOn\Documents\projects\NODETS+ANGULAR2\public\npm-debug.log
```

after, sass is absent in packege.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.2.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings":"^1.3.2"
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

Setting typescript's version to 2.0.2 helped to fix the typescript error in my case.

```
"devDependencies": {
    // other dependecies ...
    "typescript": "^2.0.2",
    // other dependecies ...
  }
```

May be this error is the result of an upgrade of the angular-compiler and it's dependencies while forgetting to upgrade the documentation.